# Set align on inserted image

Tags: froala

I'm inserting an image to my editor from an iframe with this code:

```
editor.froalaEditor('image.insert', inpImgURL.value, true, { }, null, { alt: sImgAlt, align: sImgAlign });
```

I then have a event listner on `froalaEditor.image.inserted`, where I successfully set the alt text, but Im unavailible to set the align on the image. If I try to use image.get() here it returns nothing, so I assume its not selected in the editor yet. Is there a way to select the insterted image to get this to work, or is there a better way to set the align on an insterted image.

```
$('#txtContent').on('froalaEditor.image.inserted', function (e, editor, $img, response) {
            $img.attr('alt', response.alt);
            $img.attr('title', response.alt);

            editor.image.align(response.align);
        });
```

I do know about the default settings, that I can change it to set the align, but I want to let the user choose the align when inserting an image from my image manager.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

First add a new plugin to be able to change the default options

```
(function ($) {
    $.FroalaEditor.PLUGINS.option = function (editor) {
        function change(option, val) {
            editor.opts[option] = val;
        }

        return {
            change: change
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then call it before inserting the image:

```
editor.froalaEditor('option.change', 'imageDefaultAlign', sImgAlign);        
editor.froalaEditor('image.insert', inpImgURL.value, true, { }, null, { alt: sImgAlt });
```